# how can I put multiple images and texts on a background image using Python PIL such that texts don't overlap with image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to put multiple images and texts on top of the background image. Making use of python PIL image library. The number of images and text printing won't need to be the same always. Text and image printing has to be separate. The text has to be printed outside anywhere image bounding box.
I'm using below code to make this happen

```
from PIL import Image
import os, random
with open('C:/Users/nike/Desktop/namelist.txt', "r") as word_list:
    words = list(word_list)
    k=[]
    for i in words:
        j = i.replace(' ','').replace('\n','')
        k.append(j)
folder=r"C:/Users/nike/Desktop/imagefolder"
a=random.choice(os.listdir(folder))
file = folder+'//'+a
random_text=random.choice(k)
img = Image.open(file)
img_w, img_h = img.size
background = Image.open('C:/Users/nike/Desktop/backgroundimages/back.jpeg','r')
bg_w, bg_h = background.size
offset = ((bg_w - img_w) // 2, (bg_h - img_h) // 2)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(background)
background.paste(img, offset)
font = ImageFont.truetype("C:/Users/nike/Desktop/open-sans/abc.ttf", 16)
draw.text((0, 0),random_text,(255,255,255),font=font)
background.save('out.png')
```

above code does printing of one image at the center of background image and text at the (0,0) coordinate of background image. How can I make multiple text and images to paste on background images such that text(x,y) do not print on image (x,y). Any suggestion will be helpful.
**Example:**
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKYDw.jpg)

on the background image, I need to copy images and texts such that they won't overlap eachother.

Comment: Please show a couple of examples of what you hope to achieve. At the moment more than half your code is selecting pictures and words. Just concentrate on the important stuff, which is presumably positioning one (or more?) pictures and one word (several sentences) on some background - maybe?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have included example please have a look

Comment: That's quite a vague specification - how many pictures do you want on each page? How will you know when there are enough? Will the page size change? Could you divide each page into, say 3, areas and put one image and one text in each?

Comment: no limit in the number of images and texts in each background image, minimum one image, and texts must be there on each background image and the position also doesn't matter only thing is text and image shouldn't overlap each other, shouldn't touch each other. Size of both texts and image can be different. sorry for not specifying clearly. @MarkSetchell

Comment: I presume the images can be resized to fit? And the text could be in different sizes/fonts?

Comment: Yes, the image bounding box will be smaller than the original background image, all the image i will be using of less size like the example one also test can be different sizes and font. @MarkSetchell

Comment: I would say that Pillow or PIL or any image processing library is the wrong tool for this. Look into LaTeX instead.