# How to choose multiple text coordinate such that it doesn't overlap with multiple image coordinate in a same background image using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to copy text and images on a background image using python PIL library. I want to achieve this such that new images and text don't overlap each other or touch on bordeers, they have to be separately placed on the single background image. Image size and text size doesn't concern it can be any but its need to fit inside the background image, minimum one image and text must be there. the script I have written to achieve this as below

```
img = Image.open('imagefolder').resize((600,200))
b,l = img.size
width=20
height=20   
while height<l-10:
    hmax=0
    width=10
    select = random.choice([True,False])
    ran_height = random.choice(range(5,55))
    if select:
        while width<b:
            image_folder=random.choice(image_folders)            
            imagetemp=img.open(image_folder)
            size_w,size_h=imagetemp.size
            if size_h>hmax:
                hmax=size_h
            select_word = random.choice([True,False])
            d.text([10,30], "hello", helvetica)
            d.text([90,60], "python", helvetica)
            if select_word:
                if (width+size_w)<b-10 and (height+size_h)<l-10 :
                    (x, y) = (width, height)
                    image.paste(imagetemp,(x, y))                                               
                    width = width+size_w+10
                else:
                    height = height+hmax+10
                    break
            else:
                width =width+size_w+10
        height = height+hmax+10
    else:
        height = height+ran_height+10
```

In this code ,

> d.text([10,30], "hello", helvetica) 
>   d.text([90,60], "python",helvetica)

prints text 'hello' and 'python' in the coordinate (10,30) and (90,60) respectively. and

> image.paste(imagetemp,(x, y))

prints image in the coordinate of (x,y)
I want to pass a coordinate value for text like this such that it doesn't fall under the image coordinates or texts don't overlap with an image . for example
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKYDw.jpg)
If I pass image coordinate value

> d.text([x,y], "hello", helvetica)

texts will be printed inside the image this is not what I'm looking for, I want to print outside the image. Let me know if u have any questions. I searched online I didn't find even a single example of doing this, there are many examples for copying the text inside the image using PIL, not outside the image. Any suggestion will be helpful thanks.

**Fixed it by finding the size of a text

> draw_txt.textsize(random_text, font=font)**

Comment: Please don't ask essentially the same question twice - you will annoy SO contributors and get marked down. Rather, click `edit` under your original question and update it if you are adding new information or code. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/54051261/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed it by finding the size of a text

> draw_txt.textsize(random_text, font=font)**